# custom made functions in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of films and their durations in minutes. I wish to create a custom function whereby the user selects the range of durations i.e. one or more cells. The function converts the duration in minutes into " x hours and y minutes form ".
I have created the following function but it does not seem to take more than 1 cell reference at a time.

```
Function Saikatrealtime(cell As Range) As String

    Dim r As String

    r = Int(cell.Value / 60) & " hours " & " & " & cell.Value Mod 60 & " minutes "
    Saikatrealtime = r

End Function


Sub realtimesof_film()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim t As String

    s1.Activate
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(prompt:=" enter range ", Type:=8)

    t = Saikatrealtime(rng)
    rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = t

End Sub
```

Whenever I give a reference to `rng` as 2 or more cells, it gives the error type mismatch at the line

```
r = Int(cell.Value / 60) & " hours " & " & " & cell.Value Mod 60 & " minutes "
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can modify the code so that the function runs across multiple cell references given to `rng`?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you change the formula to return an array of values, you'll have to modify the subroutine code to reference multi-cell ranges.  Adding a loop of the cells within the range will work.  Add this to your subroutine:

```
Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In rng.Cells
    Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Saikatrealtime(Cell)
Next Cell
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the custom function `Saikatrealtime`.  You can use `Format` instead.  The key is that you have to escape certain letters in the text using a backslash <kbd>\</kbd>

```
Sub realtimesof_film()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set rng = Application.InputBox(prompt:=" enter range ", Type:=8)

    For Each c In rng
        c.Offset(0, 2).Value = Format(c.Value, "HH \hour\s & MM \mi\nute\s ")
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: out of curiousity, why do you need to include a backslash before the "n" in minutes?  What kind of an output does that render?`

Comment: Wrong function. N is used to display the minute as a number without leading zeros (0 – 59). Anyway I just test it in the immediate window till I get it right. `?Format(Now(),"HH \hour\s & MM \mi\nute\s ")`  Here is the complete reference: [Format Function (Visual Basic for Applications)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx)